# Unwanted Indenting

Tags: indentation

With the following code, everything from "Scenario containing 3 pirates.." and below has been indented relative to the text above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{Giri}
\date{March 20, 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle     
\section*{Question 1}
\textit{Scenario containing 2 pirates :} \\*\\*
 Regardless of how the gold is split, the 2nd pirate will vote against the 1st pirate and take all the gold. \\*\\*

\textit{Scenario containing 3 pirates:} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{3 Pirates}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline\hline
Pirate\#1 & Pirate\#2 & Pirate\#3 \\  
\hline
x & x & x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In this...

\end{document}
```

Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: A blank line indicates a paragraph break. Paragraphs after the first are indented...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want anything indented, it is better to load `parskip`. This sets the paragraph indentation to zero and marks paragraphs with increased vertical skip while maintaining the proper formatting of environments which use `\parindent`, `\parskip` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}% if you don't want paragraphs indented but would prefer to mark them by increased vertical spacing
\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{Giri}
\date{March 20, 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Question 1}
\textit{Scenario containing 2 pirates :} \\*\\*
 Regardless of how the gold is split, the 2nd pirate will vote against the 1st pirate and take all the gold. \\*\\*

\textit{Scenario containing 3 pirates:}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{3 Pirates}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline\hline
Pirate\#1 & Pirate\#2 & Pirate\#3 \\
\hline
x & x & x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In this...

\end{document}
```

[image: Non-indented pirates]

Alternatively, you might find it easier to use a list environment to keep formatting consistent. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \newlist{pirates}{description}{1}
  \setlist[pirates,1]{font=\normalfont\itshape,style=nextline,labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,itemsep=1.5em}
\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{Giri}
\date{March 20, 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Question 1}

\begin{pirates}
    \item[Scenario containing 2 pirates:] \mbox{}\\
      Regardless of how the gold is split, the 2nd pirate will vote against the 1st pirate and take all the gold.
    \item[Scenario containing 3 pirates:] \mbox{}\\
      \begin{table}[ht]
      \caption{3 Pirates}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{c c c}
      \hline\hline
      Pirate\#1 & Pirate\#2 & Pirate\#3 \\
      \hline
      x & x & x \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \end{table}
\end{pirates}
In this...

\end{document}
```

This basically sets up a new, specialised `pirates` list formatted in a particular way. The example looks like this:

[image: pirates list]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `\noindent` before any new paragraphs. The default is that the first paragraph is not indented and all subsequent ones are.  Following a `\section` is it obvious that this is the start of a new paragraph. But to distinguish subsequent paragraphs the usual method is to have them indented.

This becomes clearer if you have longer text:

[image]

### Notes:

- The paragraph following the table is a good example of why subsequent paragraphs are indented. If this paragraph was not indented the reade would not have any way of knowing if this was the start of a subsequent paragraph or not.
- If you don't want your paragraphs indented at all, you could use:

  ```
  \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
  ```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{Giri}
\date{March 20, 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle     
\section*{Question 1}
\textit{Scenario containing 2 pirates :} \\*\\*
 Regardless of how the gold is split, the 2nd pirate will vote against the 1st pirate and take all the gold. \\*\\*

Here is some longer text to show that only the start of that paragraph is indented.
\textit{Scenario containing 3 pirates:} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{3 Pirates}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline\hline
Pirate\#1 & Pirate\#2 & Pirate\#3 \\  
\hline
x & x & x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

In this, and some more text here again to show that only the start of the paragraph is indented.

\end{document}
```